# How can I fulfill multiple orders through api call?

Tags: api, e-commerce, shopify

I want to fulfill multiple orders at a time with the help of api call. I dont want to call the api each time for each records. Is there any way or any api available to do so. Calling api every time for each fulfillment is very time taking. If somebody knows how to fulfill multiple orders through api call please do reply.

Answer (score 0):

1. use your partner account and App editing screen to add a link to order action drop down.

Any orders ticked will go to your App with their ID's

1. for each ID your App receives, make a call to the API Fulfillment endpoint with the order ID and fulfillment options you want